# Type not assignable in ngrx effect

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

I've just updated ngrx to v15.4.0 and now I'm getting an error with this action and effect:

Action:

```
export const getListReq = createAction(
    "Users - Get List",
    props<{ search: UserSearch }>(),
);
export const getListSuccess = createAction(
    UserActionTypes.GetListSuccess,
    props<{ users: User[] }>(),
);
```

Effect:

```
getusers = createEffect(
        (actions$ = inject(Actions), usersService = inject(UserService)) => {
          return actions$.pipe(
            ofType(UserActions.getListReq),
            exhaustMap((action: { search; type }) => {
              return usersService.getusers(action.search).pipe(
                map((users: User[]) => UserActions.getListSuccess({ users })),
                catchError((error) =>
                  of(UserActions.getListErr({ error }))
                )
              );
            })
          );
        },
        { functional: true }
      );
```

The error is:

> Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<User[], { users: User[]; } &
> TypedAction<UserActionTypes.GetListSuccess>>' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, { users: User[]; } &
> TypedAction<UserActionTypes.GetListSuccess>>'.

I'm obviously missing typing something somewhere, but not sure where. Any helpers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, never mind. Turns out I just had to restart my TypeScript server!

Ctrl+Shift+P > TypeScript: Restart TS Server